# Debugger doesn't stop at breakpoint in Recyclerview adapter

Tags: android, debugging, android-recyclerview

```
class testAdapter(
        private val list: ArrayList<Objects>
) : RecyclerView.Adapter<testViewHolder>() {

override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): testViewHolder {
    *BREAKPOINT HERE* 
val view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
            .inflate(R.layout.X, parent, false)
    val viewHolder = testViewHolder(view)

    return viewHolder
}

override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: testViewHolder, position: Int) {
    holder.bind()
}

override fun getItemCount(): Int { return contentList.size }

}
```

I can see that program was here, because breakpoint is check-marked. I'm pretty sure, that it's caused by async (by retrofit) call, which gathers item list, but how can I fight with this? I can write code, if I can't debug none of Adapters functions.

I set up adapter like this:

```
onCreate() {
        recyclerView =rootView.findViewById(R.id.test)
        gridLayoutManager = /* custom grid layout manager */ (this is fine)
        recyclerView.layoutManager = gridLayoutManager
}

asyncFunctionResult(list: List) {
    contentAdapter = testAdapter()
    recyclerView.adapter = contentAdapter
}
```

Sorry for pseudo code, but this should be enough. Obviously, there are alot of things wrong in adapter ect., but it should atleast get a hit [stop] from debugger. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

For anybody having this problem: try checking out if you forgot to add the `recyclerview.layoutManager`.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your list is not filled, `onCreateViewHolder` is only called when it needs to inflate an item which is when a listitem needs to be shown.

You could try to add an item to `contentlist` or `list` (as your code shows 2 lists, I assume this is also pseudocode).

Comment: Isn't `getItemCount()` function called before all that? Even if I Log simple text like "Im here!", it doesn't print out.

Comment: @JoshuaMad you are correct. `getItemCount()` is called before `onCreateViewHolder`. If a breakpoint doesn't get called in there (and it does work in the Activity) I would try to set a breakpoint in the constructor and log the list size.

Comment: Sorry, this might sound a little bit silly, but I feel like you're more experienced... Is it okay if I set adapter with 0 items at first and later on update it with list (as async call executes later on) and then notifyAdapterChanged() ? Can that cause this problem: debugger doesn't stop?

Comment: It shouldn't stop the debugger, however after calling `notifyDataSetChanged` on the main thread it should go through the `getItemCount()` method where it checks the size. Can you log and debug that?